# How can I prove that $n \sqrt{\frac{x}{n^2}} = \sqrt{x} | n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: radicals, formal-proofs

I came across this observation in an exam today, and thought that this might be useful in making certain algorithms run faster, but first I want a way to prove that this is true.  How can I do this?  I'm fairly new to proofs, outside of geometry and trig identities.

Comment: $a=\sqrt{ a^2} ,\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a \sqrt b$ if $a\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sqrt x/n$?

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathrm{sgn}\left(n\right)\,\sqrt{\, x\,}\,$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown no.  $\sqrt{20} = \sqrt{4 \cdot 5} = \sqrt{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5} 
 = 2\sqrt{5}$ and $2 \sqrt{\frac{20}{4}} = 2\sqrt{5}$ . Thus $\sqrt{20} = 2\sqrt{\frac{20}{4}}$.  $sqrt{20} \neq \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}$